# Does thinning in JAGS/Stan reduce computational time for simulating a chain of a given length?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, jags, stan

### Question

Let's say we have a complicated model whose posterior distribution we want to draw from using MCMC. To do this, we simulate a chain of total length $N=10,000$. For the sake of this question, we'll ignore burn-in/warm-up and the issue of using multiple chains, but suppose we have the option of thinning to retain only every $k$-th iterate. The final number of iterates retained from the chain would be $S=N/k$.

My question is whether there is a difference between two following thinning options in terms of how long it takes JAGS to simulate the full chain of $N=10,000$ iterates:

**-    Option 1.**  Run the chain without any thinning

**-    Option 2.**  Run the chain with thinning

### Background

There's a growing consensus that, for most purposes, analyzing a thinned chain of length $S < N$ is less statistically efficient than analyzing the full unthinned chain of length $N$. However, an argument for thinning is that it reduces computational burden in terms of requiring less computer storage, which can be helpful for models with many parameters: if you're limited to only storing posterior samples of length $M$, it's better to get that posterior sample by thinning a chain longer than $M$, since the thinned chain will have a larger effective sample size due to reduced autocorrelation.

I'm trying to understand whether another reason to use thinning might be that it makes it easier to obtain a long chain, by reducing the computational time it takes to get to, say, $N=10,000$ iterates. If that's the case, might it be preferable to use a thinned chain of length $S$ rather than an unthinned chain of length $S$?

Comment: I don't know about jags, but an alternative metric is convergence, so you might instead want to add 10,000-S to your warmup. https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_28/reference-manual/notation-for-samples-chains-and-draws.html#potential-scale-reduction

Comment: Why would it take less time to get to 10,000 iterates if you iterate 10,000 times, then throw out, say, every other one, vs. iterating 10,000 times and not throwing out every other one?

Comment: Whether there is a speed-up would depend on the implementation. For example, if the thinning is done *during* sampling rather than after sampling (e.g. only having to store half of the iterates as it goes), perhaps that reduces memory usage and thus reduces computation time. Hence the question. Obviously if the program just thins at the end of the whole sampling process, I see no reason to think that would help at all.